# Calculating between dates and an Integer

Tags: java, date

I have date say A which I get from a database. And I also get a number which is dynamic.
I want to calculate a new date using following expression

```
new date = old date + number
```

For example old date is `10/11/2014` and number is `25` then new date is `05/12/2014`

Comment: Have you tried the Calendar class in JAVA ?

Comment: @Tejas i am unaware of calender class.

Comment: You might want to check [Calendar.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int))

Comment: @user100 :- Check the answer provided by DirkNM, you'll get the hint about Calendar class.

Comment: @Tejas i am using this code in jsp .10,10,2014 are hard coded value.I placed my value there as Date da = ag.getCreatedOn(); Calendar x = new GregorianCalendar(da.getYear(), da.getMonth() - 1, da.getDay()); But it gives da.getyear getmonth,getday deprecatad

Comment: Check my answer @user100. I have added some code which I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Calendar x = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 10, 10);

    Date date = x.getTime();

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);

    Date newDate = cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(newDate);
}
```

Comment: i am using this code in jsp .10,10,2014 are hard coded value.I placed my value there as  Date da = ag.getCreatedOn();                                                                                                                            Calendar x = new GregorianCalendar(da.getYear(), da.getMonth() - 1, da.getDay());  But it gives da.getyear getmonth,getday deprecatad

Comment: You can skip the first line in the example and use your Date `da` directly with the Calendar `cal`. You don't need a Calendar `x`. It was created just for my example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  Date afterAddingTenMins = new Date(dateFromDb.getTime() + (numberInMinutesToAdd * 60000));

                or

You can also use Calendar class which is best date manipulation

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(oldDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numberOfDaysToAdd);
Date newDate = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at joda date/time library

sample code:

```
ISODateTimeFormat.basicDate().parseLocalDate("20141110").plusDays(45);
```

You need to use a *DateTimeFormat* implementations (such as *ISODateTimeFormat*) to define, how your date/time string looks like and how it can be parsed onto an object.

Note, that there are several date/time abstractions with different sematics: DateTime, LocalDate, LocalDateTime

I would recommend to write Test Cases with some samples of date+offsets including the leap year case.

regards

Comment: Why does it always have to be an external library?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
       import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
       import java.util.Date;

    /**
      *
      * @author Sajana
        */
      public class NewClass8 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

      String dt="12-05-2014";//////////MM DD YYYY
    int dt1=25;/////////days you want 

     java.util.Calendar cal1 = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();

       StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer(dt);
   String year = sBuffer.substring(6,10);
   String mon = sBuffer.substring(0,2);
   String dd = sBuffer.substring(3,5);

      int calyear = Integer.parseInt(year);
   int calmon = Integer.parseInt(mon);
   int caldd = Integer.parseInt(dd);
   caldd=caldd+dt1;

   cal1.set(calyear, calmon, caldd);

   Date d1=cal1.getTime();
     SimpleDateFormat t;
   t=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   String vb=t.format(d1);
   System.out.println("Date"+vb);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Let me know if it helps you.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, YearValue);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, MonthValue);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, DayValue);

    c.add(Calendar.DATE, AdditionalDayValue);

    Date d= c.getTime();
```

This is what I use to do Date calculations in JAVA